# Closed Loop AGC

Tags: transfer-function

Interested to develop an AGC for the RF RX chain below.
[image]

Using the Matlab code as a [reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.agc-system-object.html) have developed an open loop AGC.
Equations as well as block diagram are provided below.
[image]
Wondered how can this be converted into a closed loop structure.

Update:

Seems that the following is a more relevant design.
https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/fskd.2012.6234143
[image]
Will review further and update.

Comment: Your output will affect the gain of your variable-gaib amplifier which in turn will affect the signal level digitized by your ADC. For starters do you have a model of your VGA? Either closed-form (Laplace) or a frequency response.

Comment: Secondly, your AGC is non-linear which prevents you from obtaining a transfer function.

Comment: However, you could linearize around a point of operation to get a linear model valid around this point (i.e. gain)

Comment: Thank you Ben.
Seems that the following is a more relevant design.
https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/fskd.2012.6234143
Will review further and update.